# JSF Delay rendering of a component

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, delayed-execution, mojarra

I'm using JSF/2.0 with vanilla Mojarra.

I've got a list  table of clients loading up on a screen, and 10 seconds after the screen loads, I want to put an individual dollar value next to each client name.

I'm thinking of extending an existing JSF component to do this. What's the best way to do this?

JG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call has to come from the client side since the standard HTTP protocol doesn't allow the server side to push stuff to the client side. Start with JavaScript's [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function.

```
<script>setTimeout(functionName, 10000);</script>
```

You could use plain JS (or even jQuery) to do the changes. If you need to invoke a JSF action, call the [`jsf.ajax.request()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.request) function.

Comment: is it possible with jsf.ajax.request() to execute a bean method? e.g.#{myBean.calculateDollarValues} so afterwards he can access the updated properties. It doesn't seem clear from the docs, the example suggest to me that execute would actually hit the commandButton - but it doesn't.

Comment: @Toskan: Only if the component is present in the view, or when you use a custom component which doesn't render anything, but takes it into account in `decode()`.

Comment: ah... okay. I understood that to execute something you need a component (e.g. h:commandLink) which does it for you in any case (whether somehow hacky not rendered, hidden or just plain visible). But how would you, using the js function jsf.ajax.request, submit that commandLink?